# Sqlite3 vs Mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I'm working with a RoR application right now for grabbing and breaking down tweets by hashtag, I've always worked with Sqlite3 but now I'm getting a suggestion to use mysql2. Can anyone tell me what the broad strokes are in difference? I mean they both seem like reliable databases each with editing and query power.

Comment: They are, but my guess is that you'll have an easier time finding a host that uses MySQL than SQLite. For example, if you're pushing to Heroku, you have to use Postgres. Every Rails site I've ever worked on that is hosted at Amazon runs on a MySQL database. If you're referring to the mysql2 gem, you can still develop using the sqlite3 database locally.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that's what I needed to know.

Comment: @NickM if that solved OP's question, then I suggest adding it as an answer below, with some references if possible. Your comment answers the question much better than the current answer below. In no way does OP even mention Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, @onebree. I converted my comment to an answer. Will add references if I can find some.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not designed to replace Oracle. It is designed to replace fopen().

Read other things from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Answer (score 1):

They are, but my guess is that you'll have an easier time finding a host that uses MySQL than SQLite. For example, if you're pushing to Heroku, you have to use Postgres. Also, every Rails site I've ever worked on that is hosted at Amazon runs on a MySQL database (I'm sure you can use Postgres at AWS as well).

If you're referring to the mysql2 gem, you can still develop using the sqlite3 database locally. Rails migrations are designed to work  on MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite, and possibly others, enabling you to use separate technologies for dev/test/production.